# Least Squares Matrix Notation Correlation

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, matrix

Consider the model $Y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \epsilon$,
where the columns $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the design matrix have mean 0 and length 1.
That is $x_i' x_i = 1$, and $x_i' J = 0$, for $i = 1, 2$, where $J$ is a vector consisting entirely of ones. Let $p$ be the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Show that, 
$$\begin{align}X'X & = 
\begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & p \\
0 & p & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} .
$$

**I can easily show that numerically with a $3 \times 3$ matrix of:
$$\begin{align}X & = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\sqrt{.5} & -\sqrt{.5} \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & \sqrt{.5} & \sqrt{.5}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align} .
$$

However, I'm not sure how to generalize this beyond a $3 \times 3$ (for example, a $10 \times 3$).  Any guidance would be appreciated.

**

Answer (score 3):

Generalization is pretty straightforward given the definition of the correlation coefficient and what is known:

$$\begin{align}X'X & = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
X_{11} & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{1n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
X_{m1} & X_{m2} & \cdots & X_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & X_{11} & \cdots & X_{m1} \\
1 & X_{12} & \cdots & X_{m2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & X_{1n} & \cdots & X_{mn}
\end{pmatrix} \\
& = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{1} & \boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{X_1} & \cdots & \boldsymbol{1}'\boldsymbol{X_m} \\
\boldsymbol{X_1}'\boldsymbol{1} & \boldsymbol{X_1}'\boldsymbol{X_1} & \cdots & \boldsymbol{X_1}'\boldsymbol{X_m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\boldsymbol{X_m}'\boldsymbol{1} & \boldsymbol{X_m}'\boldsymbol{X_1} & \cdots & \boldsymbol{X_m}'\boldsymbol{X_m}
\end{pmatrix}\\
& =
\begin{pmatrix}
n & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & \rho_{1m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \rho_{m1} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
n & \boldsymbol{0}' \\
\boldsymbol{0} & \boldsymbol{Q}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$

where $\boldsymbol{Q}$ is the sample correlation matrix.